# Progres bar starts from outside the parent container

Tags: css

You will see the small red at the extreme left hand side. The progress starts from outside.
It also doesnt take the shape of the container which has certain border radius.

```css
.progress-bar {
  background: grey;
  width: 90%;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.progress-line {
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: red;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 2px;
}
.upload-percent {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar">
<div class="progress-line">
</div>
<div class="upload-percent">
Uploading... 72%
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: please note that you should respond to the answerer(s) of your questions, you haven't replied to none of your questions... please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use overflow hidden on outer div like below:

```css
.progress-bar {
  background: grey;
  width: 90%;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.progress-line {
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 2px;
}
.upload-percent {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar">
<div class="progress-line">
</div>
<div class="upload-percent">
Uploading... 72%
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using the above styles, will hide the Upload-percent content too.

Answer (score 1):

Take the "upload-percent" out and apply overflow:hidden to progress-bar.

```css
.progress-bar {
  background: grey;
  width: 90%;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.progress-line {
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 2px;
}

.upload-percent {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="progress-line">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="upload-percent">
  Uploading... 72%
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.progress-bar {
  background: grey;
  width: 90%;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

your .progress-bar class update is sufficient.